# HTTPS-only Play Framework on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, playframework

Setup: Play Framework application deployed on Amazon EC2 instances via ECS, Elastic Load Balancer in front. I want to allow only HTTPS requests for the application.

I found several ways to use HTTPS with Play, but what are the pros and cons, or which one is best practice for a (dockerized) Play app?

1. Enable HTTPS directly within Play (with -Dhttps.port or https.port in config file).
2. Set up a front-end web server (e.g. Nginx) and let it handle the HTTP->HTTPS rewrite ([example](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/)).
3. Implement a request filter in Play and redirect the requests within the application ([as described here](https://www.clever-cloud.com/blog/engineering/2015/12/01/redirect-to-https-in-play/)).

I'm not so keen to use the first version as I would have to manage the certificates separately on each instance, but I listed it for the sake of completeness.
One advantage I can think of for the third approach must be that the system architecture is simpler than in the second version and requires less configuration. Are there any disadvantages (e.g. performance) to using the third approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a load balancer then you should request a free SSL certificate from the [Amazon Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) service and then attach that certificate to the load balancer.

To enable HTTP to HTTPS redirects you simply need to check the `x-forwarded-proto` header that the load balancer passes to the server. If it is `http` return a 301 with `https`. The article you linked covers this part.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding Certificate Manager. I know that the forwarding can be achieved with the articles I linked. However I would like to know which approach one should use to achieve the forwarding - directly in Play or with a dedicated webserver in front? Are there any (dis)advantages (e.g. performance) to either approach that I should be aware of?

Comment: There's no real advantage/disadvantage to either approach. If you aren't already using a reverse-proxy server then I wouldn't worry about setting one up, as it will add complication and use up some of your server's RAM.